# Unknown Error When Attempting to Display Flurry Banner Ad

Tags: ios, swift, flurry

I'm trying to display a banner ad on an iOS app using Yahoo's Flurry

```
class GameViewController: UIViewController, FlurryAdBannerDelegate{
    // ...

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool){
        // this ad space does exist
        self.advertisement = FlurryAdBanner(space: "LevelBannerBottom")
        self.advertisement!.adDelegate = self
        self.advertisement!.fetchAndDisplayAd(in: self.view, viewControllerForPresentation: self)
    }

    // ...
}
```

When I do this, no advertisement is displayed, and `Error in AdRequest: [Unknown Error]` is printed to the console. There's no non-Flurry errors anywhere, or any crashes.

The ad space does exist (I'm pretty sure). I've also tried replacing setting the ad space to the number underneath `Ad Unit ID` (which I removed before uploading this image) -- `FlurryAdBanner(space: "123456")` -- ` but that gives the same result. 
[image]

I've already waited 24 hours since I added the new ad unit, and I have added my device's IDFA under *Test Device IDs* on the dashboard.

I have debugging turned on, so a lot of stuff is printed to the console, but the most important stuff is this (I've removed all of the times and app name)

```r
Successfully parsed ad request schema
Load AdUnit Timed out
Picked cached ad unit 0x0 with guid (null)
Successfully created ad request.
Sending AdRequest....
Sending AdRequest of size 1456....
Flurry: HTTP connection delegate received response[<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x17402eba0> { URL: https://ads.flurry.com/v16/getAds.do } { status code: 200, headers {
       Connection = "keep-alive";
       "Content-Length" = 57;
       "Content-Type" = "application/octet-stream";
       Date = "Tue, 11 Oct 2016 02:52:52 GMT";
       "FM-Checksum" = 734757664;
       "Keep-Alive" = "timeout=10";
       Server = nginx;
   } }]

This is a ad response of len 57
Successfully parsed ad response schema 
Error in AdRequest: [Unknown Error] # << this is the important error
FlurryAdCache: skipping adunit with empty or nil adspace
******* logAdEvent:
  ** [<FlurryAdEvent: 0x170249000> unfilled(4), T:10040] 
    ** <FlurryAdLog: 0x170461a80> [S:1476154362553, RS:1476154362553 ID:1, GUID (null), {(
        "    ** [<FlurryAdEvent: 0x170249000> unfilled(4), T:10040] "
    )} transmitted {{
  }} ]**
********************
```

Although this shouldn't be causing the problem (I didn't have to provide any information about the app anywhere), the app isn't public on the iOS App Store yet.

What could be causing this error? Is it something to do with iOS 10? I'm using Flurry 7.6.6

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is the result of a bug.  Please try this work around:

1. Log in to https://dev.flurry.com
2. Click 'Classic Flurry' in the upper right corner
3. Click the applications tab
4. Select your app
5. Go to Manage -> App Info
6. See if you have a category assigned to your app
7. If not set a category and wait an hour or so
8. Retry the ad integration

Otherwise send us your api key and ad space name to support@flurry.com and we can look into it.

Comment: This solved the issue, although I am now getting a different error (117). But that isn't related to this question. Thank you!